Stats Models Patsy Testing, Python
I am trying to compare different conditions via a contrast test. However, I am not interested in the overall means of these conditions, rather he differences in the interactions between the conditions and the DV, on the IV (both DV and IV are continuous).
One step of this is to do f_test patsy testing, however no matter how I try to format it, I receive an error.
I am new to stats and coding, so if my statistical approach is all wrong please let me know!
model = smf.mixedlm(
    formula = "pPrime ~ Condition * Target_Contrast",
    data = df,
    groups = 'Participant_Number'
)
result = model.fit()
#print(result.summary())
levels = model.exog_names[0:4]
print(levels)

This successfully outputs the conditions that I am interested in:['Intercept', 'Condition[T.Straight]', 'Condition[T.Target]', 'Condition[T.back_C]']  so that in the f_test I try:
f_val, p_val = result.f_test(hypo)```
I have also tried formatting it as a matrix including all the parameters of the `result`: ```hypotheses = np.array(
    ([1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0],
     [1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0],
     [0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,1,0,-1,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0])
     )```
When using the Patsy I get this error:`PatsyError: unrecognized token in constraint
    (levels[0] != levels[1]), (levels[0] != levels[2]), (levels[0] != levels[3]), (levels[1] != levels[2]), (levels[1] != levels [3]), (levels[2] != levels[3])` ; when using the matrix I get this error: `ValueError: wrong shape for coefs`


hypo needs to be a string or list of strings for linear equality hypothesis. In case of the restriction matrix, the number of columns needs to be the same as the length of params. (There is not enough information to see what you actually did)
